# unable to access $rootscope property declared in one controller in other in angular using typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript1.5

I have declared a rootscope custom property in a ts file  like below

```
module MyApp.Entity{

    export interface IRootScope extends ng.IRootScopeService {
        userData: any;
        clientData: any;
    }
}
```

In one of my service file I have assigned value

```
    export class Service1 {

            constructor(private apiService: MyApp.Common.Services.apiService, private notificationService: MyApp.Common.Services.notificationService,
                 private $base64: JQueryBase64Static, private $cookieStore: ng.cookies.ICookieStoreService, private $rootScope: MyApp.Entity.IRootScope) {
            }

    saveData(){
    this.$rootScope.clientData = clientData; // Data got assigned 


    }
}
```

Now in other Controller file I was trying to access this rootscope property

```
class controller2{
Clients: any;
constructor(private service1: MyApp.Service.Service1, private $rootScope: MyApp.Entity.IRootScope){
this.Clients = this.$rootScope.clientData; // clientData is Undefined i.e here //it is creating new rootscope again I guess ..so How to access a single global //rootscope
}
  }
```

Comment: `this` is specific to the module / scope currently running, unless you bind a different scope.

Comment: yes, then how to resolve? Any idea?

Comment: This is a bad practice. Why do you want to use globals like this? Services are singletons, you better be using them instead to share data.

Comment: Contrary to previous comments and answers accessing `this.$rootScope` in a controller class with `constructor(private $rootScope)` is absolutely legitimate. My best guess is that you have minification problems. Adding `static $inject = ['service1', '$rootScope'] //dependencies` to your class would fix that

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this.$rootScope` which is a different instance of $rootScope since it is only defined in your current scope if you remove the `this.` it should work

Comment: when I remove this. in controller where I am using the rootScope no error but when I remove in Service too where I'm Declaring then .. Cannot find name '$rootScope'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.$rootScope'?    even though in service this. is placed and removed in controller where I'm using still undefined