# How to use $rootScope define in one angular service in another service using typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript1.5

I have declared a $rootScope in a service class (in contstructor) and assigning in a method using this.$rootScope and assigning property to it and when I want to use in another service again in that class I am declaring in constructor which is creating new $rootScope and that property is undefined

How to Resolve this?? Is It Possible ? and how we do in angular??

I already posted this question 
[unable to access $rootscope property declared in one controller in other in angular using typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482539/unable-to-access-rootscope-property-declared-in-one-controller-in-other-in-angu)

EDIT :
As said in answer if I have written code like

```
     export class DataService {

        betterApproach = "value";

        constructor(private $rootScope: any){
            $rootScope.someProperty ="some value";

        }


    setBetterApproach(data){
          this.betterApproach=data;
    }
        getBetterApproach() {
            return this.betterApproach;
        }
    }

    angular.module("services").service("dataService", ['$rootScope', DataService]);

        angular.module("services").service("dataService", ['$rootScope', DataService]);

How shoud I use??

        export class ConsumingService{
    test:any;
    constructor(private $rootScope: any ,
                private dataService : DataService ){

        this.test = $rootScope.someProperty;

        this.test = dataService.getBetterApproach();  // Still returns old value
    }


}

angular.module("services").service("ConsumingService", ['$rootScope', 'DataService',ConsumingService]);
```

So you when I'm calling setsetBetterApproach?? In DataController How??

```
    class DataCtrl{

    constructor(private dataService: Dataservice){

       }


    myData(){
     //this is ng-Click function
    this.dataService.setBetterApproach("new Data");
    }
}
```

Some Where I messed up and still getting value in betterApproach as value only not newData

Comment: You better be sharing data using services, which are singeltons, instead of using globals. Globals are considered bad practice and you should try to avoid them as much as possible

Comment: I also want to use service as they are singleton  but how??? When I create service I want in constructor I want to consume it is creating new variable .

Comment: I am sorry, but it is hard to understand what are you trying to do. Can you try to clarify please?

Comment: I don't what's so hard in that to understand? I declare a varaible in a service and want to use that in another service that's it...!      In constructor when I create instance of service which  I have to use data is not persisting..!    Did you get that????    We have rootscope in angular to share some data as requires like global So I thought using that ... Both aren't working!!!

Comment: At First you should tidy up your code and remove  `$rootScope` entirely. Are you sure your `myData()` method is really called? You are trying to get butter approach in the constructor. There you will never get your changed data from `myData()`

Comment: In your proposed solution also you have got data in constructor only right ? This line  "this.test = dataService.getBetterApproach();"

Answer (score 1):

you want to use the same $rootScope instance?

Then you should inject your $rootScope into your services but not creating new ones...

like:

```
export class DataService {

    betterApproach = "value";

    constructor(private $rootScope: any){
        $rootScope.someProperty ="some value";

        betterApproach = "other value";
    }

    getBetterApproach() {
        return this.betterApproach;
    }
}

angular.module("services").service("dataService", ['$rootScope', DataService]);
```

Consuming Service:

```
export class ConsumingService{
    test:any;
    constructor(private $rootScope: any ,
                private dataService : DataService ){

        this.test = $rootScope.someProperty;

        this.test = dataService.getBetterApproach();
    }


}

angular.module("services").service("ConsumingService", ['$rootScope', 'DataService',ConsumingService]);
```

Why your example not worked:

- you have to write `this.test` to access your class variable
- `$rootScope` is likely not from type ng.cookies.ICookieStoreService, create your own interface for $rootScope

When you are injecting your DataService into your Consumingservice then you don´t need $rootScope  at all, take a look at `betterApproach`, You even can access it directly like `dataService.betterApproach` but using the getter function is a way much more cleaner.

Comment: @kabaeher I have edited question, please check the problem

Comment: @kabaeher  I have edited the question now, I cannot retrieve data .Can you please check I have updated question

Answer (score 0):

To use dataService which you had created you need to write:-

```
import {DataService} from 'pathName';
```

Basic implementation of above part is:-

Declare an interface for DataService class for abstraction of variable/methods.

```
export interface IfcDataService {
    getShare(): string;
    setShare(data: string): void;
}
```

import dataService interface and define its functions in it.

```
import {IfcDataService} from 'pathName for IfcDataService';

export default class DataService implements IfcDataService{
   public share: string = "injectDataService";

   constructor(){

   }

   public getShare(): string{
       return this.share;
   }

   public setShare(data: string): void{
       this.share = data;
   }
}

DataService.$inject=[];
```

To use dataService in another service class, import its interface method.

```
import {IfcDataService} from 'pathName'
import {IfcUseDataService} from 'pathName'

export class UseDataService implements IfcUseDataService{


public dataService: IfcDataService;

constructor (dataService: IfcDataService) {
   this.dataService = dataService;
}

    public useDataService() {
       console.log(this.dataService.getShare());
    }
}

UseDataService.$inject = ['DataService'];
```

Do not define common variable on $rootScope, it might effect your testing.
define setter and getter for global variable in dataService and inject dataService.ts to use it in their respective places.

Refer [For large scale application see architecture and github code](https://medium.com/@bojzi/anatomy-of-a-large-angular-application-f098e5e36994#.dgmais72c).

Comment: I have tried above , but I'm getting "injectDataService" value only not the data which I set

Comment: did you register the services on main App?

Comment: angular.module("SameModuleNameAsService").controller("consumingController", ['DataService',consumingController]);

Comment: angular.module("SameModuleNameAsService").service('DataService', DataService);
checkout the link given in the answer. for more info see its github project.

Comment: Actually I'm setting the service variable in a controller function and redirecting to another html page usnig window.href , is due to that it is not maintaining stae??